# How To Speed Up Printing Unicode?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I'm using windows.h "TextOutW" function to print text to a bitmap. Printing regular ascii is really fast, but the printing in the unicode range seems to cause a huge slowdown. Here's my code to print a unicode square & test the duration:

```
wchar_t b = 0x25A0;
LPCWSTR s = &b;
TextOutW(hMyDC, x, y, s, wcslen(s));
```

Are there any ways of speeding this up?

EDIT:
I ran my loop with a timer to test speed:

```
    using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
    using std::chrono::duration_cast;
    using std::chrono::duration;
    using std::chrono::milliseconds;



auto t1 = high_resolution_clock::now();

for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++){
    TextOutW(hMyDC, 25, 25, s, 1);
}
  
auto t2 = high_resolution_clock::now();

  //  auto ms_int = duration_cast<milliseconds>(t2 - t1);
duration<double, std::milli> ms_double = t2 - t1;
    cout << ms_double.count() << "ms\n";
```

Printing 'H' a 1000 times took around 5ms
and printing 0x25A0 1000 times took around 50ms

Comment: There shouldn't be *any* speed difference between different parts of the Unicode range, unless font substitution needs to occur.  What kind of speed difference are you seeing?

Comment: You aren't passing a valid string into `wcslen` nor `TextOutW`.

Comment: @MarkRansom I'm running the TextOutW function a bunch in a row to draw to the BitMap and if I use: wchar_t b = 'H'; I see around 30fps, but with:  wchar_t b = '0x25A0' I get around 4ish fps

Comment: Does it look right when you use `'H'`?  You should be using a wide char constant, so `L'H'`.

Comment: @MarkRansom It does display correctly when I just use 'H'

Comment: Yes, I just realized - since you're assigning to a `wchar_t` variable, the compiler will automatically upcast it for you.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh ok cool!

Comment: Why not  `TCHAR s[] = { 0x25A0, 0 };`. Your `b` is not zero terminated.

Comment: @i48 Because **no one** uses `TCHAR`'s anymore. And your code doesn't do what you think it does when `UNICODE` or `_UNICODE` aren't defined. Regardless, if you want to render a single code unit, just pass `1` and be done with it.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh!, Do I have to define unicode somehow?

Comment: No, **you** don't. You are using the Unicode API, and explicit wide characters. None of that depends on build configurations. Things change if you switch to `TCHAR`s, which - as I noted - no one uses anymore. It's a left-over from the times when Microsoft had 2 different lines of OS', one that didn't support Unicode, and one that did. Today, there's only one OS. At any rate, we still cannot see how you determine the slowdown.

Comment: @IInspectable Oh ok thanks for the clarification! Hmm I'm not sure how to programmatically determine slow down, so I would love some help with that! Here's the code: https://github.com/wawesomeNOGUI/ScreenASCII/blob/main/asciiScreen.cpp

Comment: It's still a little messy, but should I post all of it here too?

Comment: @IInspectable And who is working in ANSI mode? Maybe `wchar_t` is shorter and easier for typing than `TCHAR`? Don't say `"no one uses" ... at least I use it (plus thousands other).

Comment: @i486 Windows itself uses wide characters internally, so if you use ANSI mode functions it has to do a conversion anyway.  Your earlier example wouldn't work as an ANSI string because 0x25a0 doesn't fit in a single byte and wouldn't be a valid character even if it did.

Comment: @i48 The **only** purpose of the generic-text mappings (like `TCHAR`) is to be able to compile a single source base to run on Windows NT and Windows 9x. The [MSLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Layer_for_Unicode) alleviated even that need. The MSLU shipped **two** decades ago. So even if you are one of the few developers that still have to target an OS that has been out of support for more than 15 years you wouldn't even need `TCHAR`s. Though, you are correct, of course. I should have said: *"No one in their right mind would recommend to use `TCHAR`s"*.

Comment: @IInspectable Just updated my question with a timer.

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks for explanation of `TCHAR` purpose. I am programming Win16/Win32 since 1993 and maybe I know this. I do not recommend to use `TCHAR` - it was example how to define 2 wchar array with zero termination instead of pointer to 1 character and undefined (non-zero) next char. What about `LPCWSTR` - maybe it is also forbidden like `TCHAR`? Relax - I see you are angry.

Comment: @i486 Thanks for the info on TCHAR, I didn't know about that data type, so I'll look into that too!

Comment: @NO_GUI It is not real data type but macro which is `char` for ANSI applications and `wchar_t` for UNICODE. You can write portable code and re-compile/switch easily between ANSI and UNICODE. But I find it shorter and easier to read than `wchar_t`.

Comment: @i486 Oh ok cool!

Comment: @i48 `LPCWSTR` serves a **completely** different purpose than `TCHAR`. It maps language-level types to ABI types. Unlike `TCHAR`, `LPCWSTR` is unambiguous. If you see it in code, there's no question what it maps to. Unlike `TCHAR`, which requires a reader of your code to go looking through your build configuration to know what it is, and raises the question as to whether changing that code needs to be compatible with ANSI and Unicode. Using `TCHAR` makes code **harder** to read and comprehend, with no benefit at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting Uniscribe. `ExtTextOutW` and `TextOutW` check if text should be threaded through Uniscribe or passed directly to GDI.

To avoid Uniscribe overhead (NOT RECOMMENDED) you can pass `ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE` to `ExtTextOutW`, but you will miss some more advanced scripts (CJK aka Chinese+Japan+Korean, right to left writing, characters changing shape depending on where they are placed etc.) or get no text at all.

For 0x25A0 character I get slowdown about 8×

For 0x6F22 slowdown increases to 17×

On my system, when `ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE` is specified there is no slowdown. 0x25A0 displays correctly, 0x6F22 is replaced by default box.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I wasn't able to get the square character on my system with `ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE` specified, but I used the `ETO_OPAQUE` option to get a similar effect. : 
`ExtTextOutW(hMyDC, x, y, ETO_OPAQUE | ETO_IGNORELANGUAGE, NULL, s, 1, NULL);`

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're pointing to a single character, not a string.  The `wcslen` is exhibiting undefined behavior and probably returning a very large number.  Replace it with `1` and things should speed up greatly.

Comment: Like this: TextOutW(hMyDC, x, y, s, 1); ?

Comment: @NO_GUI yes, exactly.

Comment: It definitely sped up a bit, but it still seems much slower than drawing an H

Comment: We can neither see a [mcve] that does the rendering, nor how you are measuring the speed. Either one can be wrong.

Comment: @IInspectable Ooo ok I'll add some more

Comment: @MarkRansom I added in a timer to test performance and edited my question

Comment: @MarkRansom Also I tested with `TextOutW(hMyDC, 25, 25, s, 1);` and `TextOutW(hMyDC, 25, 25, s, wcslen(s));` and there was no difference in the times I listed in my question.

Comment: @NO_GUI you got lucky then.  It's still undefined behavior though.

Comment: @MarkRansom Oh I see! So it might overflow, but not everytime

Comment: Do you think there's anything else I should look into to find the source of the slowdown?

Comment: @NO_GUI as I said in my first comment on your question, it might be due to font substitution - but I have no idea how to test for that.  Maybe try a third character choice that you know is part of the font, but is in an unusual part of the Unicode range.

Comment: @MarkRansom Ooo ok I'll try that! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer. I just want to post the code to confirm the timing from this question.

I am getting 7-8 ms for the commented out characters, and ~50 ms for that `0x25A0`.

I use `Times New Roman` because [this page](https://wutils.com/unicode/9632/fonts-all.htm) claims that it has that UNICODE symbol.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t b = 0x25A0;
    //wchar_t b = 0x0416;
    //wchar_t b = L'H';

    LPCWSTR s = &b;
    HDC hDC = ::GetWindowDC(::GetDesktopWindow());
    HFONT hFont = CreateFontW(36, 20, 0, 0, FW_DONTCARE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, DEFAULT_CHARSET, OUT_OUTLINE_PRECIS,
        CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS, CLEARTYPE_QUALITY, VARIABLE_PITCH, L"Times New Roman");
    HGDIOBJ hOld = ::SelectObject(hDC, hFont);
    auto t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        TextOutW(hDC, 25, 25, s, 1);
    }
    auto t2 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

    std::cout << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(t2 - t1).count() << " msec" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```